# Software that allows for "scoping" in CSS with encapsulating brackets

Tags: css, csstidy

In the past I've used some software which does this, but I can't recall the name. I thought CSSTidy did it but I can't seem to recall how (if that was it).

Basically the way it worked is you could pass a CSS file like:

```
#foobar{

    .red {

        color: #FF0000;

    }

    .blue {

        color: #00FF00;

    }

}
```

And then it would return a CSS file like:

```
#foobar .red {

    color: #FF0000;

}

#foobar .blue {

    color: #00FF00;

}
```

That way I could dynamically encapsulate some CSS includes and ensure their CSS does not "break out" to some extent. ShadowDOM doesn't work for this because I want to cascade into this element. It's not intended to prevent malicious code, just simplify development.

I'm fairly certain it was server-side software and not a javascript library, though either would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sass, Less, and other CSS preprocessors is what you're looking for!

Here's a [good article](https://www.slant.co/topics/217/~best-css-preprocessors-postprocessors) that compares some of the more popular options.

Comment: Less is the one I was thinking of. Thank you!